# Android HttpPost. Sends data to a form on a PHP server

Tags: android, http-post

I am using the latest java Eclipse software and the emulator crashes when I run this HttpPost code. I installed uniserver on my laptop and so I'm using it as the server.

This code is supposed to call the edit text data from a previous class and use an HttpPost request to post this data into their respective fields on the online form.

The edit text data are 3 fields: "From", "To" and "Message". And also the form I created on the server has these same fields to input data. ("http://19x.xx.xx.xxx/androidp2p/testform.php") Where 19x.xx.xx.xxx is my (localhost) IP address.

I am pulling that data correctly from the previous class and my code is similar to the HttpPost examples I found online but I am not sure why it crashes.

I attached the HttpPost methods I tried to see if I can get any assistance. Thanking you in advance.

Method 1:

```
String myBreadu, myBreadr, myBreadm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle myBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    myBreadu = myBasket.getString("keyfrom");
    myBreadr = myBasket.getString("keyto");
    myBreadm = myBasket.getString("keymsg");
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String postURL = ("http://19x.xx.xx.xxx/androidp2p/testform.php");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
    try {
        // Add the data
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keysendu", myBreadu));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keysendr", myBreadr));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keysendm", myBreadm));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity uefe = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs);
        post.setEntity(uefe);
        // Execute the HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        // Convert the response into a String
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        uee.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
        cpe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Method 2:

```
String myBreadu, myBreadr, myBreadm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle myBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    myBreadu = myBasket.getString("keyfrom");
    myBreadr = myBasket.getString("keyto");
    myBreadm = myBasket.getString("keymsg");
    String result = null;
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String postURL = ("http://186.45.107.129/androidp2p/testform.php");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
    try {
        // Add the data
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keysendu", myBreadu));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keysendr", myBreadr));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keysendm", myBreadm));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity uefe = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs);
        post.setEntity(uefe);
        // Execute the HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        // Convert the response into a String
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String l = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((l = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(l + "\n");
        }
        rd.close();
        String result = sb.toString(); // this line gives an error "Duplicate local variable result"
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        uee.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
        cpe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is the testform.PHP

## Test Form

From:
To:
Message:

Can I add one more thing please? I am not sure if I should be sending the data directly to the form or this other PHP page I have..

By the way the errors I get in the logs when I try to HttpPost are:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-07 11:36:23.226: E/AndroidRuntime(1490): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.keegan/com.project.keegan.SendPostMethod}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

03-07 11:36:23.226: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)

03-07 11:36:23.226: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)

03-07 11:36:23.226: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
```

Sorry if this is too much information guys. Thanks.

Comment: No, information is never too much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do all your network operations.

Your network operation can take a lot of time and the UI would get unresponsive if it is done on the main UI thread. And if your UI freezes for a long time, the app might get killed by the OS.

Thus Android 4+ makes it mandatory to use a background thread to perform network operations.

Put the code to do the network activity inside **`doInBacground()`** and all the AsyncTask using **`execute()`**.

Here is how your AsyncTask would look like :

```
private class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String postURL = ("http://19x.xx.xx.xxx/androidp2p/testform.php");
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
try {
    // Add the data
    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keysendu", myBreadu));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keysendr", myBreadr));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keysendm", myBreadm));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity uefe = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs);
    post.setEntity(uefe);
    // Execute the HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    // Convert the response into a String
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    if (resEntity != null) {
        Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
    uee.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
    cpe.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
        
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    //called when the background task makes any progress
 }

  protected void onPreExecute() {
     //called before doInBackground() is started
 }
 protected void onPostExecute() {
     //called after doInBackground() has finished 
 }
  }
```

And you can call it anywhere using **`new SendData().execute("");`**

Comment: Thank you very much swayam, the application does not crash anymore. However, no data is displayed on the PHP form.

Comment: This is the error log message: E/Trace(1175): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: It is usually better to make one question per post as it makes it easier for others to understand your problem. This post is about the application crash, which has been fixed. So, I advise you to make another post with the new problem and the detailed LogCat output. And don't forget to *accept/upvote* my answer.

Comment: Post a separate question and give me the link here. I will try my best to help you. :)